# How to export objects that are coming as arguments in a function in JavaScript (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, oop, design-patterns

Let me explain the problem clearly I have a class which is in fileA looks like this

```
  // This is in FileA
import {twoClass} from "fileB"
class oneClass{
      public async functionA(varA){
              return value
   }
}
var twoClassObject = new twoClass()
var oneClassObject = new oneClass()
twoclassObject.funtionB(oneClassObject)
```

In fileB I have a twoClass which looks like

```
// This is in FileB No import in File B
export class twoClass{ 
  returnedObject: any;
  public funtionB(objectOfOneClass){
    this.returnedObject = objectOfOneClass
    console.log(await this.returnedObject.functionA(arg)) // prints the value in consloe
  }
}
```

As I am exporting this class I should be able to access it wherever I import the class right? But in fileC if I do this

```
// This is in FileC only should import File B but not File A
 import {twoClass} from 'fileB'
 var twoClassObj = new twoClass()
 console.log(await twoClassObj.returnedObject.functionA(arg))  // gives me an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'functionA' of undefined
```

Comment: You are never assigning anything to `returnedObject`.
You have to call `funtionB` with `oneClassObj ` so that it can access it's functions.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, I have not got your answer could you please elaborate more? Is this.returnedObject = objectOfOneClass, not enough?

Comment: How are you importing and exporting `fileA`?

Comment: I am starting the execution of my program from fileA which in turn invokes function in fileB. I am not allowed to call file A in File B or File C.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "I am not allowed to call file A in File B or File C" and I am still unsure how you're exporting and importing your class(es) from `fileA` - it's unclear.

Comment: @goto1 I have made edits if its unclear feel free to comment

Comment: What you're trying to do **will not work**. Just because you instantiate a class inside `FileA` doesn't mean that instance will be available in that context when you import `TwoClass` inside `FileC`. What are you trying to do exactly? Maybe there's a better solution to what you're getting at.

Comment: I need a way where I can use the object of oneClass to be used in fileC without using any import statement from fileA. If I have this object I can use all the methods of oneClass in fileC right. I can use fileC as dependency in fileA, but not fileA in fileC. Am I clear on this?

Comment: @RohithReddy let me get this straight - you want to use `OneClass`, which is in `FileA`, **without** exporting and importing it in `FileB` and/or `FileC`? Do I have that correct? Or is it OK to import it in `FileB` but not in `FileC`?

Comment: Yes, you have it correct. I have to create objects for oneClass and use them in `fileB` and `fileC`. File A should not be imported in `fileB` or `fileC`. But you can import `fileB` and `fileC` in `fileA`

Comment: @RohithReddy what you want is **not** possible. I am curious where you got these requirements from and what's the reasoning behind this.

Comment: @goto1 I am creating a package A which has file A and Package B which has file B. Package A can have Package B in its dependency but not vice-versa. But I was able to achieve one part by `this.returnedObject.functionA(arg)` calling this in file B (see above question. It logs the value!). So I need a way how to export this object to other classes

Comment: @RohithReddy again, you **cannot** use things from `FileA` in `FileB` or `FileC` without exporting things from `FileA` and importing them in at least `FileB`. You could, however, export things from `FileA`, import them in `FileB`, then use `FileC` to import `FileB` that uses things from `FileA`, if that make sense.

Comment: @RohithReddy also, it's hard to tell what you got working so far because none of those examples in your question are actually correct, so you must be doing something different if you got something to work.

Comment: @goto1 the working part is the last line in first part of code is invoking function in `fileB` and it is able to console.log the value in `fileB`. So I am assuming there should a way to export that object

Comment: In `FileB`, without any imports? This - `this.returnedObject.functionA(arg)`? That's impossible. What is `objectOfOneClass` referring to in `FileB`?

Comment: As I have imported FileB in FileA I was able to invoke the function in FileB. `objectOfOneClass` refers to an instance of class in file A

Comment: Could you recreate this in CodeSandbox and share it? https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

In you fileC

```
 import {twoClass} from './fileB'
 var twoClassObj = new twoClass()
 console.log(twoClassObj.returnedObject.functionA(arg)) 
//here you are calling directly the returned object from twoClass, but actually returned object is empty as you haven't call the functionB till now with a parameter of onClassObject
```

What you are trying to do can be achieved by the code bellow:

**fileC**

```
import {twoClass} from './fileB'
import {oneClass} from './fileA'
var oneClassObj = new oneClass()

var twoClassObj = new twoClass()
console.log(await twoClassObj.functionB(oneClassObj))
```

**Updated**

in fileB

```
import {oneClass} from './fileA'
class B {
    constructor() {
        this.returnedObject = new oneClass();
    }
     public funtionB(){
       return this.returnedObject.functionA(arg) // prints the value in consloe
  }
}
```

In fileC

```
import {twoClass} from './fileB'
var twoClassObj = new twoClass()
console.log(await twoClassObj.functionB())
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer I need a way where I should not import fileA in fileC.

Comment: You cannot call `await` outside of an `async` function, unless you have an environment that supports `top-level await`, but I doubt that's the case in this situation.

Comment: In my understanding its not possible because, you will need a object reference of oneClass . Unless you call  the oneClass and create a object reference of that class and pass it to twoClass, returnedObject will be undefined and it will create error.

Comment: I have updated my solution. You can create a object reference of oneClass inside of twoClass and pass it to functionB. In that case , you will not need to create a object of oneClass or import fileA

Comment: But you can also check my updated answer. We can do this in a different way

Comment: Hi, I should not import fileA in either fileB or FileC so I have invoked a function of fileB in fileA to get the object. And I am able to get the object in fileB but how to pass it on to file C?

Comment: @goto1 async and await are not the issue here I have await in async functions only

Comment: When you invoked a Instance of `fileA` and called `fileB`, that instance was different from when you calling `fileB` in `fileC`. Two are completely different instances and you can not access the previous instance of `fileB` from `fileC`

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Is there a way to achieve this? I have tried using static objects but did not wok out

Comment: I dont think there is anything like this as it will violate the rule of OOP.

Comment: @Arnab I have made some edits to question. Please feel free to ask if its unclear

Comment: You are exporting twoclass and yes you can import it from anywhere you want by creating an instance. but `public funtionB(objectOfOneClass)` here you have to pass an argument which is basically the object instance of oneClass. Unless you re initiate the twoClass and oneClass object both in fileC you are never gonna be able to acces the function of oneClass. you fileC dont know the `oneObject`. It only knows the twoClass as you initiated an object in fileC. Same thing, your fileB dont know the `oneObject` unless you initiate it in `fileC`. So its not possible as it violates the rule of OOP

Comment: @Arnab. I need a way where I can use the object of oneClass to be used in fileC without using any import statement from fileA. If I have this object I can use all the methods of oneClass in fileC right. I can use fileC as dependency in fileA, but not fileA in fileC. Am I clear on this? Can you suggest a way to do this?

Comment: As far as I understand, without importing `fileA` and creating instance in `fileC `, you can not use the methods of `fileA`